# Is there a way to randomly select multiple values from an array in python?

Tags: text

For example, in making a text based game, I'm trying to select a few countries out of a whole array, like only a few not the whole thing, but it needs to be random and different every time. I'll try display it in pseudocode:

```
Import random
nations = [UK, USA, France, Spain, Germany, Russia, Sweden, Norway, Austria, Turkey, KSA, UAE, 
India, PRC, Japan, Mongolia, Kyrgyzstan, Egypt, Algeria, Morocco, Nigeria, Ghana, Laos, 
Vietnam, Cambodia, Congo, Kenya, Somali, Sudan]
nationsForThisGame = nations.random(9)
// This gives me 9 random nations from that array
output(F"You are allies with {nationsForThisGame(1)}")
// This means that from the second array called nationsForThisGame, the first nation you're 
allies with
```

Now how do I make this into python? I tried this similar structure, but it says: 'list' object has no attribute 'random'

So from the first array, I just want a few random values to put into my second array. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
Nations = ["Nation1", "Nation2", "Nation3", "Nation4", "Nation5", "Nation6", 
"Nation7", "Nation8", "Nation9"]
print(random.sample(Nations, 6))
```

It works good.

This means that from the array 'Nations', you could randomly choose as many values as you want. This helped me in a text-based game I'm making.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?